# jQuery not selector is not working, what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, except

I want to alert something when user clicked anywhere in the document except the div that has class = 'reset_btn'. I have tried both not() and :not(selector) but they are not working.

This is my code.

```
$('document').not('.reset_btn').click(function(){
   alert('Something');
});
```

I have created a demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr8SA/). In demo they aren't alert anything. It should alert when I clicked any area outside the div and should not alert when I clicked in div area.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('document')` is not a valid selector, since there's no `document` tag name. You could instead use `$(document)`, which'll use the `document` *element*, but that's not needed here. Just use `:not()` directly:

```
$(':not(.reset_btn)').click(function(){
   alert('Something');
});
```

---

To optimize this further, you should use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.reset_btn)', function(){
   alert('Something');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate event to document.

```
$(document).on("click", ':not(.reset_btn)').click(function(){
   alert('Something');
});
```

Comment: On is used to bind event could be click, mouseenter, mouseleave etc.